# Correct type annotation for a celery task

Tags: python, celery, type-hinting

I am looking for the correct type annotation to attribute to a celery task which has been set by the celery `@task` decorator.

Assume I have a function `run_task` that takes in some celery task.

```
@task(name='adder')
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


def run_task(taskfn: "?", *a, **kw):
    # do something here
    taskfn.apply_async(args=a, kwargs=kw)
    ...


>>> run_task(add, 1, 2)  # usage
```

My confusion lies here:

```
>>> from celery.task import Task
>>> from celery.local import PromiseProxy
>>> type(add).__name__
'PromiseProxy'
>>> isinstance(add, Task)
False
>>> isinstance(add, PromiseProxy)
True
```

It seems like `PromiseProxy` is some kind of "future" or "promisary" proxy that holds the task (or something like that, [I haven't looked too far into it](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/local.py#L290)).

This wouldn't be an issue, I could easily do `taskfn: PromiseProxy`, but then `taskfn.apply_async` wouldn't make sense since there is no method `apply_async` on a `PromiseProxy`. So, my question is, should I do what `type` tells me to, or think in terms of duck-typing and go with `Task`?

Comment: As a quick fix, you could just have it take a union of both: `taskfn: Union[PromiseProxy, Task]`

Comment: Thank you but I would rather not do that, both because it's not a rigorous solution and also because I don't really need a "fix". Mainly want to see the discourse regarding what to do in these situations

Comment: You could take in the task as a PromiseProxy and then explicitly cast it to a Task inside your function, before you call the Task methods. Possibly Celery should implement the subclass/instance check magic methods to show what type the Proxy is for: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks

Comment: @alkasm thank you, that is great advice. Do you mean to cast via `typing`: `typing.cast(taskfn, Task)`?

Comment: Yeah. It's still not perfect: this is codifying the assumption that all possible proxy objects you get do indeed proxy into a Task. That is probably reasonable for you, but isn't proof the types line up. The Proxy type really needs a way to tell you what type it proxies into for true typing here. Still, the cast is nicer than a Union here IMO.

Comment: Well I think it's safe to assume that by the time we get to `apply_async`, it should be a task. But I see what you're saying. Also, for what it's worth I just went with Task.. didn't use Union.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this just for IDE detecting delay method

```
from celery import shared_task
from celery.app.task import Task


def my_task(compound_ids: list[int] | None = None):
    print(1 + 1)


my_task: Task = shared_task(my_task)
```